# STM8: How to make External Interrupt Handler firing only once

Tags: interrupts, stm8, gpio-external-interrupt

I have a external interrupt handler which is tied to a button which will be fired upon pressed.

```
INTERRUPT_HANDLER(EXTI2_IRQHandler, 10)
{
   if(mode == 2){
      mode = 0;
   }
   else{
      mode++;
   }
   EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_IT_Pin2);
}
```

But the issue is, it works like a `while(1)` loop when the button is pressed, for example, if I pressed the button long enough when `mode = 0`, it will keep running like a loop (mode keeps adding up and go back to 0) until I release the button and it will landed on `mode = 2` or `mode = 0` again. But I want is this handler only fires once no matter how long I press the button, the code will only ran once. Does STM library have some sort of thing to limit this or I have to find a way to hardcoded it

Configuration of the External Interrupt

```
EXTI_SetPinSensitivity(EXTI_PIN_2, EXTI_Trigger_Falling);
```

Configuration of the GPIO Pin for the Button

```
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_2, GPIO_Mode_In_PU_IT);
```

[image: The Schematic of the Button]

Comment: detecting a button press does not mean that a button release is automatically detected

Comment: That won't even compile, please fix the typing errors. And if this is about STM8 then it is not about STM32, which tag you want to remove?

Comment: Please post the code for configuring the interrupt. You should be able to setup for rising or falling edge interrupt only. Then of course, if it's connected to a push button you also need to consider contact bounce. Either handle it in SW or filter the input with HW.

Comment: Also a scratchy button has contact bounce which will trigger multiple interrupts with one button press, so if the init code has no error to make it level sensitive, and the pin is really edge sensitive, it will still trigger multiple interrupts. Which is why it may not be a good idea to generate interrupts from push buttons to begin with.

Comment: @Justme right, it's STM8. And it can be compiled with STM's Peripheral Library.

Comment: No the code has syntax error; that will not compile.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny just updated, the interrupt is set to Falling only, can you explain more about SW and HW?

Comment: @Justme just a typo. Fixed. Also I did thought about contact bounce at the beginning so I used pull-up resistor and capacitor to made out a R-C circuit to filter out the bounce already, or did I done it incorrectly?

Comment: @Scarittagle SW = Software, add some filtering (for example, store the current time each time the interrupt fires and check if long enough time has passed before doing anything in the interrupt again). HW = Hardware, add some RC filtering on the input to mitigate the issue to begin with. Google "RC debouncing".

Comment: @Klas-Kenny okay, then I already applied RC Filtering for the button.

Comment: @Scarittagle How did you connect the RC and what values are you using?

Comment: The old errror is still there and now there's unbalanced curly braces that leave a block open so it is not fixed. And we don't know how you RC filtered the button so we can't comment if it was made properly or incorrectly. Show the scematics. Is there any other things regarding the button and IO pin initialization we should know about? Has it been initialized as input? Is there a pull-up or pull-down enabled? Any external resistors? Should we assume pushing a button makes the IO pin low?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny schematics has been updated.

Comment: I´d try increasing R7 to something like 47k, and remove R8, that is of no use.

Comment: @Justme your option? after Kenny's input.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny by doing so will make it less sensitive, right?

Comment: @Scarittagle Yes, increasing the RC time constant will make everything slower. Right now you have a time constant of like 200 µs, my experience from contact bounce is that it can bounce for several milliseconds, which needs to be filtered away. 47k and 0.1µF will have a time constant of 4.7 ms, so it will filter away significantly more contact bounce. If that doesn't help, I'd go back to troubleshooting the interrupt itself.

Comment: "it works like a while(1) loop when the button is pressed" No, that doesn't make any sense. The GPIO interrupt should trigger on rising and/or falling edge of the signal.

Comment: Also the RC filter should be a series resistor and a cap to ground.

Comment: @Lundin ikr? It did triggered on Falling edge, that how I set it that way. But the thing is it seems keep looping the code when signal is LOW

Comment: @Klas-Kenny just swapped R7 to 47K and it did have some improvement! Although it would still acting weird occasionally. Does it mean I should increase the value of R7 even more?

Comment: @Scarittagle Then it's confirmed to be contact bounce and not the interrupt acting up.
You can increase R more, or C. Using 1uF instead of 0.1µF is probably effective.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I tried up to 100K on R7 and 1uF and the problem still occasionally exist (at least it's better than the original setup). I think we need to dealing it on the SW side now....

Comment: @Scarittagle The normal way interrupts work is that there's a flag set which is the cause of the interrupt and this flag must be cleared from inside the ISR or you'll keep getting the interrupt over and over.

Comment: @Lundin I think `EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_IT_Pin2);` is used to clear the flag you are referring to.

Comment: Do you think or so you know? You can single step through that function/macro or maybe even view the source. Also you should inspect the relevant GPIO flag register in your debugger when single-stepping through the ISR.

Comment: Every time I see, in this site, a push-button read in interrupt, I see also debouncing problems. To solve simply, use a periodic interrupt, perhaps every millisecond, and poll your button there. Enable pull-up on the input pin, and remove R and C components - hardware debouncing is uncertain unless you have a schmidt trigger in your input pin.

Comment: @Lundin I knew. As it's stated in the official STM library manual. I tried to single step through but reason I stated that it sorted of worked like a while loop is if I put a breakpoint in the `INTERRUPT HANDLER` (which means every time I press the button the code will be stopped for me to clear it), all the problem goes away. `mode` will be increase and go back to 0 like the code make it suppose to be, and no bouncing.

Comment: Anyways, it's indeed not a good idea to connect a switch to an interrupt-triggered pin. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557921/how-to-detect-two-or-more-button-press-gpio-at-the-same-time-by-a-microprocess/23559522#23559522. A periodic timer interrupt is a much better solution